# Mongodb find query with date diff on two keys

Tags: mongodb

Let say I have a database date entity with two date fields

```
{
   createdAt: "2022-01-01",
   updatedAt: "2022-01-02"
}
```

Is there any way to get all the entities where the difference between `createdAt` and `updatedAt` is less than three days ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate the dates aren't BSON dates, but anyway, here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$lt": [
      {
        "$dateDiff": {
          "startDate": {"$toDate": "$createdAt"},
          "endDate": {"$toDate": "$updatedAt"},
          "unit": "day"
        }
      },
      3
    ]
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PaUmXe11USf).

If `"createdAt"` and `"updatedAt"` are already BSON dates, then the query is a bit simpler.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$lt": [
      {
        "$dateDiff": {
          "startDate": "$createdAt",
          "endDate": "$updatedAt",
          "unit": "day"
        }
      },
      3
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong format, but my dates are BSON dates

Comment: Then just drop the use of `"$toDate"`. I updated the answer.